# How Can I Add A Spinner Dynamically(By Press Of A Button)?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am new to Android Programming, I have been trying to add a spinner with a button click, my wonder is i always keep getting an error, I can not find a solid answer anywhere, Can somebody please help me?
below is my code
it tells me inSpinner cannot be created and that CreateFromResource() is array adapter cannot be applied.

.Java File

```
Button add;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make__questionnaires);


    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Add);

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    LinearLayout newLinear = new LinearLayout();


    Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.question_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    newSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    newSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    newLinear.addView(newSpinner);


    setContentView(newLinear);


    RelativeLayout root_layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    root_layout.addView(newSpinner);
}
```

Comment: it tells me inSpinner cannot be created  on the Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(this) line and   and that CreateFromResource() is array adapter cannot be applied  on the  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.question_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) line respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know that this in the OnClickListener class is indicating to it not the Activity class. and You need to pass the context of your activity to the (Spinner, LinearLayout, ...) constructor so to get the context of your activity you use `NameOfTheActivityClass.this` instead of using this directly.

I don't know your logic, but I need to mention that you can add the spinner to the main layout of the activity not inflating a new layout from scratch and `setContentView()` again.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        LinearLayout newLinear = new LinearLayout(AddSpinnerDynamicallyActivity.this);


        Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(AddSpinnerDynamicallyActivity.this);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                AddSpinnerDynamicallyActivity.this, R.array.question_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource
                (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        newSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        newLinear.addView(newSpinner);


        setContentView(newLinear);
    }});
```

Comment: But how can i add a new Spinner without setting up a new layout? I was Hoping to add multiple other Spinners according to user needs, lets say the user needs 4, they can easily add 4, but i cannot think of such logic

Comment: let's say your main view is activity_make__questionnaires. You can findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_root_view) to you layout. whatever type it was and just add the Spinner you created to it directly. Got me?

Comment: Thank You very much, I have sat for hours now trying to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly add the Spinner in your Root Layout which is **RelativeLayout** in your case. I have solved your problem. I am sharing the **Layout design**, **Java code** and **Screenshots** here. Please leave a comment if I'm able to help you.

**Layout File -->**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout">

      <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium"
        android:text="Add a Spinner"
        android:onClick="add"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml file -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Hoster</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">Main</string>
<array name="spinner">
    <item> Airtel </item>
    <item> Vodafone </item>
    <item> Reliance </item>
    <item> Aircel </item>
    <item> BSNL </item>
</array>
```

**Java Code -->**

```
private RelativeLayout root;
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.experimental);
    root = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
}

public void add(View v){
    spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.spinner,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    root.addView(spinner);
}![Added on Button Click][1]
```

Comment: You make the array inside the strings.xml folder. I'm adding it to my previous answer. There you can get the structure of String.xml. Please tell me whether you are able to figure out that or not !!

Comment: thank you, it worked, though it was overlying the previous one but i did manage to fix it, thanks a lot.